# .Net Maui SearchBar magnifying glass doesn't show up in dark mode

Tags: maui

My Samsung S22 has an operating system menu option mode called "Dark Mode". I noticed that when my phone is in dark mode, the magnifying glass icon for the searchbar is missing. Only seeing this with my samsung device. Did some google searches and couldn't find anybody else mentioning this. Is this a Maui bug?

Comment: You mention only on Samsung. It does not happen if you use an Android emulator, and set Android's "Display / Dark Theme" ON? Possibly experiment with [Theme an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/theming?view=net-maui-7.0), to explicitly set all the app colors, for light or dark theme.